# How to configure Python read/write module?

Tags: python

I have an assignment where my task is to measure the time it takes for Python to read an infile, and consequently write a number of 'a':s in an outfile, for every character in the in-file. My code looks like this:

```
import time

#opening input file for reading and output file for writing
#assume in.txt file created e.g. from cmd.exe using command:
# fsutil file createnew in.txt 20000000
#which creates a text file of ~20MB filled with dots.
#double backslash is required as escape character on Windows
inputFile = open('C:\\Users\\Benson\\in.txt', 'r')
outputFile = open('C:\\Users\\Benson\\out.txt', 'w')

start_time = time.time()

for i in range(1, 100):
    while True:
    #reading file by 1 character
    ch=inputFile.read(1)
    #end loop if no more characters left
    if not ch: break
    #for every character read - write an 'a' to output
    outputFile.write('a')

print("%s" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

However, when I run the program I find that the number of characters in the out-file does not correspond to the number of characters in the in-file. For the in-file I have used an excerpt from Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, about 1300 words. However the output file consists of only 99 'a':s whereas they should be about, or exactly, 1300 in total. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please fix your indentation. This code wouldn't even compile.

Comment: This is not your code. You don't have anything indented under `while True`, so it would immediately give an IndentationError.

Comment: But in any case, since you have a loop that only counts up to 99, I'm not sure why you think it would ever write more than that many characters.

Comment: Fixed indentation.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I completely forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop is 1,100 which would give you 99 reads. Try instead using,

```
`For i in inflile:'
```

The change your code to use i. i will be a line of the file, by default will be all chars apart of a new line.

Comment: I tried this, but now it just produces a output file with the single character 'a'.

Comment: Well, put another loop in the original where it reads through i.

Comment: And print i to see what i is. I don't know what the file looks like.

Comment: The file is exactly 1300 words long.

Comment: Did you print i?